# Are the members of a global structure initialized to zero by default in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Are the members of a global or static structure in C guaranteed to be automatically initialized to zero, in the same way that [uninitialized global or static variables are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)?

Comment: Yes. (for `static` variables).

Comment: If the variable is initialized to zero, how could it possible that their members aren't, given the fact that a struct consists of their members..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the C99 standard 6.7.8/10 "Initialization":

> If an object that has automatic
>   storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has
>   static storage duration is not
>   initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is
>   initialized to a null pointer;
>     — if
>   it has arithmetic type, it is
>   initialized to (positive or unsigned)
>   zero;
>     — if it is an aggregate, every
>   member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules;
>     — if it is
>   a union, the first named member is
>   initialized (recursively) according to
>   these rules

Since globals and static structures have static storage duration, the answer is yes - they are zero initialized (pointers in the structure will be set to the NULL pointer value, which is usually zero bits, but strictly speaking doesn't need to be).

The C++ 2003 standard has a similar requirement (3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local objects"):

> Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

Sometime after that zero-initialization takes place, constructors are called (if the object has a constructor) under the somewhat more complicated rules that govern the timing and ordering of those calls.

Comment: Thanks, perfect.  That third point was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Local variables are not initialized.

```
struct foobar {
    int x;
};

int main(void) {
    struct foobar qux;
    /* qux is uninitialized. It is a local variable */
    return 0;
}
```

static local variables are initialized to 0 (zero)

```
struct foobar {
    int x;
};

int main(void) {
    static struct foobar qux;
    /* qux is initialized (to 0). It is a static local variable */
    return 0;
}
```

Global variables are initialized to 0 (zero)

```
struct foobar {
    int x;
};
struct foobar qux;
/* qux is initialized (to 0). It is a global variable */

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` is no different in this manner than a *normal* static C variable.  The memory reserved for that `struct` is completely initialized to 0 if it's a static.

Comment: Is the memory initialized to zero, or are the actual fields initialized to zero?

Comment: Memory is initialized to zero.

Comment: @Victor: I'm not sure there's a difference, from the point-of-view of the standard.  I assume you're wondering what happens to padding bits/bytes; but the value of these "doesn't matter".

Comment: For instance, initializing the memory of a pointer to zero does not initialize that pointer to null. So, is the initialization a simple ZeroMemory, or does it actually do the "smart" thing and initialize every field with its actual zero value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all global data is zeroed out, including the members of structures, classes and unions.

Answer (score -3):

All data in global part of the program is set to zero.

> The BSS segment also known as
>   Uninitialized data starts at the end
>   of the data segment and contains all
>   uninitialized global variables and
>   static variables that are initialized
>   to zero by default. For instance a
>   variable declared static int i; would
>   be contained in the BSS segment.

[Bss segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss).

I don't know why is it so hard to try it yourself btw.

Comment: Because "try it yourself" does not differentiate between standard behavior and implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: This really isn't something that any major compiler implementation would dare to change.

Comment: Even then, knowing whether it's a standard guarantee or merely an implementation status quo is a good enough justification for asking the question.