# GCC variable uninitialised within local scope

Tags: c, gcc

Most uninitialised errors in C seem to come from scope as in this answer: [Uninitialized Structures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080673/uninitialized-structures-in-c).

However in this example I have declared all my variables in the same scope. I cannot find a direct answer to why the gcc compiler would warn about uninitialised variables. How to initialise my variables without errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a,b,c;
  a =+ 3;
  b -=2;
  c = 0;
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",a,b );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: None of these values have been initialised - local variables left uninitialised take on an *indeterminate* value, while global variables left uninitialised take a "default" value (0 in most cases).

Comment: What are the inicial values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: my confusion has come from this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/461887 specifically static variables. I expected a default value of 0 to apply but it does not.

Comment: The referenced question doesn't answer directly my question. However I have no idea how to edit my question to help people in the future.

Comment: @sayth The relevant quote from that answer is: "Non-static variables (**local variables**) are **indeterminate**. Reading them prior to assigning a value results in undefined behavior". Your `a`,`b`,`c` variables are non-static local variables, and so are not initialised to `0` automatically.

Comment: @hnefatl     i agree in hindsight but to a beginner in C not so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **declared** your variables `a` and `b` but they are not **initialized** when you use them.

Non-static local variables need to be **initialized**. It means you need to **assign a value** to these variables after declaring them.

You should have something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  int c;

  a =+ 3;
  b -=2;
  c = 0;
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
  return (0);
}
```

Otherwise, when you do `a =+ 3`, your `a` variable is declared but still does not hold any value. The same happens with `b` at the moment when you do `b -= 2`.

Comment: Ok I see my error. In this stackoverflow answer it shows that variables are defaulted to zero which must not be true https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/461887

Comment: Here, you are declaring non-static local variables. As explained in this SO answer, these variables have an indeterminate state when declared. As opposed to static local variables and global variables, which have a default value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a,b,c;
a =+ 3;
```

`a` is uninitialized and then initialize it 3<sup>1</sup>. The variable `b` however is uninitialized and you subtract 2 from an uninitialized value. `c` is declared but later initialized (with 0).

The results are meaningless because this is undefined behaviour. Of course GCC
will warn about it. What did you expect?

**edit**

Only global variables and static variables are initialized with 0 before the `main` function run. Local variables **are not** initialized. In your example `a`, `b` and `c` are local variables, hence **you** have to initialize them.

---

**fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>I initially misread the code and interpeted the second line as **`a += 3`**. Then my explanation would be correct, that
it would add 3 to an uninitialized value. But in the case of **`a =+3;`** it is
the same as **`a=3;`** and this would initialize `a` with 3. I don't know if you
intended to do that or you wanted to to `+=` and incorrectly entered `=+`.

Comment: I expected that int a,b,c; initialised all values to a int default of zero.

Comment: Well, that's not what happens. Only global variables are initialized with 0, local variables are not initialized. `a` and `b` are local variables.

Comment: I have commented this on another answer but I got that impression from another SO answer which shows it does https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/461887

Comment: @sayth read my answer. I said that only global variables and static variables (in a function) are initialized with 0. `a`, `b` and `c` are local variables but they are neither global nor static.

Comment: `a =+ 3` doesn't add 3 to `a`, it sets `a` to 3. In other words, the compiler sees that line as `a = (+3)`.

Comment: `a=+3;`  sets `a` to `+3`, which is perfectly fine. `a+=3;` would attempt to add `3` to an uninitialised value.

Comment: @user3386109 @rici I gee, I misread that as `a += 3`, you are right.